# Jquery Image rotate and toggle are not working at a time in IE8 and IE9

Tags: jquery

Requirement is when we click the image,the image should be rotate and respective below data should be hide and again when we click the image, the image should be rotate and respective hided data should be show.

Like in visual studio 2010 solution explorer when we click image button, the image is rotating and respective below data is hiding.

My code is working fine for Google cromo and Mozilla. but in IE8 and IE9 its not working properly.

**My plugin**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQueryRotate.2.2.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
```

**My code for IE8:**

```html
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var deg = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#imgId').click(function () {
            deg = deg ? 0 : -90;
            rotationDeg = 0;
            switch (deg % 360) {
                case 0:
                    rotationDeg=0;
                    break;
                case -90:
                    rotationDeg=3;
                    break;
            }
            $('#divId').slideToggle("slow");           
            $("#imgId").css('filter', 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=' + rotationDeg + ')');
            $('#divId').Toggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

The above code is working fine, but it it showing the below javaScript error.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'Toggle'

Then I changed it to

```
$('#divId').toggle("slow");
```

Now the javaScript error is resolved, but image rotation and `toggle` is not working properly. The same problem happens with IE9 also. Can any one help this - how can I resolve it?

Comment: "is not working properly" You should elaborate on this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
var deg = 0;
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#imgId').click(function () {
               deg = deg ? 0 : -90;
               rotationDeg=0;
               switch(deg%360){
               case 0:
               rotationDeg=0;
               break;
               case -90:
               rotationDeg=3;
               break;
               //<---------removed the '}' here
  $('#divId').slideToggle("slow");           
$("#imgId").css('filter','progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+rotationDeg+')');
 $('#divId').toggle("slow");

       });
});
       </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I removed '}' this. Then now its working properly in IE9. But in IE8 its not working. showing javascript errors in jQueryRotate.2.2.js plugin.

Comment: can you give a link to that file here.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/downloads/detail?name=jQueryRotate.2.2.js                                       I used above jQueryRotate.2.2.js plugin

Comment: this._container.style.rotation=(angle%360)+"deg";     i am getting javaScript error here. it showing runtime error: Failed